# UDID error.. new apple UDID rules..

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

Following are the problems that are showing in error message during upload of a game developed through Unity 3D.

1. Your app contains non public API usage. Please review the errors, correct them, and resubmit your applications.
2. Apps aren't permitted to access the UDID and must not use the unique identifier method or UIDevice. Please update your apps and servers to associate users with the vendor or advertising identifiers introduced in IOS6. 
   can anyone suggest how to remove the functions that use UDID

Comment: Well the error are quite clear, some where in you app you are requesting the UDID, something that Apple is not allowing for some time now. Remove any code where you are retrieving the UDID and/or update your unity version.

Comment: can u suggest which functions are responsible for accessing UDID, and if i remove them , will it be error free, one more thing, i have updated all the plugins, but the error still persists.. what to do

Comment: I'm sorry, I have never worked with Unity and therefore have no idea which part could be causing the issue.

Comment: thanks.. @rckoenes...your suggestion give me a direction to work up on

Comment: What Unity version are you using? Have you tried updating it?

Comment: @golergka, i have updated it to the latest, and all the plugins have also been updated.. don't know whats the problem.. do you know what is the latest version of PLAYHAVEN plugin for ads..thats where the problem must be existing

Comment: I don't know about this exact plugin, but I've had problems like this caused by different plugins. Try a binary search on the plugins you use to check if they are to blame.

Comment: ok @golergka i will take a look on this.. thanks for suggestion.. and will tell u if I get the results